# updating product/vendor id on Raspberry Pi (CP210X)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, usb, raspbian

Running "uname -a" on my Raspberry Pi will yield the following:
Linux tm-gw 4.4.14-v7+ #896 SMP Sat Jul 2 15:09:43 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

My problem is that I have a USB device which vendor and product ID isn't registered in CP210x.c file, which - again - means that even though it can be found, the raspberry will not allow communication with it (/dev/ttyUSB0 doesn't exist).

I have tried to download the kernel, add the ID pair to the cp210x.c file, rebuild and install, which works. (dmesg will show "usb 1-1.4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0")

Since I have to install this program on more than one raspberry it takes too long, so I'd like to know if it is possible to inject the usb ID's without recompiling the kernel ??

I did try to take the cp210x.ko file from the kernel I build and install it to a new raspberry by typing "sudo insmod cp210x.ko" but that didn' work.

/Karsten

Comment: A kernel module can be loaded only when the module version numbering matches exactly. If you were booting the raspberry pi with the kernel you build for, insmod cp210x.ko should work. If you want to keep the old kernel but load the module which was build against the kernel source on which you did the change, it will not work.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you should be able to do `echo VEND PROD > /sys/bus/usb-serial/cp210x/new_id` where `VEND` and `PROD` are the 4-digit hexadecimal vendor and product IDs of the new device. You'll probably have to do a `modprobe cp210x` before that. If it works, put the commands in a local startup script.

Comment: @Sanchayan: I tried to load the new .ko module in the old kernel, and you are right: it didn't work :-D

Comment: @Ian Abbott: I tried your solution, but when I run "sudo echo 10c4 84cc > /sys/bus/usb/cp210x/new_id" I get the error "-bash: /sys/bus/usb/cp210x/new_id: No such file or directory". (I ran "sudo modprobe cp210x" first). Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: @KarstenL It's `/sys/bus/usb-serial/cp210x/new_id`, not `/sys/bus/usb/cp210x/new_id`. Also, the `>` redirection doesn't work as you intended with `sudo` because the redirected output file is opened by the shell as the current user. You can either run `sudo -s` to open an interactive shell with superuser privileges before running the command, or do something like `sudo sh -c 'echo 10c4 84cc > /sys/bus/usb-serial/cp210x/new_id'` to run the command with redirection in a non-interactive shell with superuser privileges.

Comment: OK I found the solution. I used the modprobe command as you said, and found out that under usb-serial you have to go to drivers before cp210x, BUT the echo command didn't work.I therefore moved to the cp210x directory, did a "sudo nano new_id" and inserted the vendor and product ID. After inserting the USB plug everything worked :-D Thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry .. didn't see your last comment due to not updating before writing my comment. I did write udb-driver and not usb in the link, but after a short time you cannot edit .. it seems :-) ... but again: Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry I missed off the "/drivers" part. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ian Abbott for the solution.

Run "sudo modprobe cp210x"
then

sudo sh -c 'echo 10c4 84cc > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/cp210x/new_id'

When plugging in the device it works :-)

Comment: Glad you got it working. What is this device exactly? I can submit a patch to the appropriate Linux maintainers and mailing lists if you like.

Comment: @Ian Abbott, It is a controller for a biomass boiler system that we are interfacing to a RP so it would be great if it could be part of the list of approved devices. Actually I'd like to know how to apply for changes since we have a few more ID's that should be implemented.

Comment: Heed the advice in "Documentation/SubmittingPatches". It's basically a case of creating a patch against the current "linux-next" kernel with a proper summary, description and "Signed-off-by:" line. For an example patch to the cp210x driver, see the output of `git show --format=email 6627ae19` in a Linux git repository. It's best to work in git as it can generate patches (`git format-patch`) and even email them (`git send-email`). See "USB SERIAL SUBSYSTEM" in the kernel MAINTAINERS file for where to send the patches.